# MS Word - copy / paste a table and keep view of comments/revision in pasted version

Tags: copy-paste

I have a table with comments and revisions showing in the right margin, I want to copy this table into the document in a later section. How can I paste it and have the comments and revisions show?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a copy is something new so the review marks and review comments from the old location do not belong in the new.

If instead you moved the table, lets say by selecting it and dragging it with the mouse, it should at least keep the comments. The review marks will change anyway since they relate to the document and moving the table is itself a change that requires a set of review marks.

Comment: I need the table in both locations in the document. I was able to complete this by turning off the tracking function prior to the copy paste function and it kept the comments and revisions and did not see it as a revision. thank you for your suggestion

Comment: @lgreen: Post that as an answer then.